# How can I ensure clients can only join one room with socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chatroom

I'm including some one to one real time messaging functionality in my application with socket.io and need to ensure that clients can only exist in one room at a time. I'm calling a function when a user closes the chat area which emits the request to the server where I'm using socket.leave to remove the client from the room. However, when I then join another room the client also rejoins the previous room and can only send messages to the previous room. Hopefully the following code will help demonstrate exactly what I'm trying to achieve and how I'm going about it.

**Client**

A user joins a room by clicking on an icon in their list of friends. This passes a unique chat id to the following joinRoom function.

```
var joinRoom = function(id) {
    var room = id;
    socket.emit('join', {room: room});
};
```

When the user closes the chat area they call the following leaveRoom function with the same id.

```
var leaveRoom = function(id) {
    var room = id;
    socket.emit('leave', {room: room});
};
```

**Server**

On the server side I have the following.

```
socket.on('join', function(data) {
    socket.join(data.room);
    rooms[userId] = data.room;
    console.log(rooms);

socket.on('leave', function(data) {
    socket.leave(data.room);
    delete rooms[userId];
    console.log(rooms);
```

You can see from the above that I'm also adding the session id and room/chat id to a `rooms` object when a user joins, and deleting it when they leave (which console logs as expected).

I've also been using `io.sockets.client()` to track rooms, and I get the output below if user 1 and user 2 join a room, then user 1 leaves that room and joins a room with user 3.

`'580119d779dfb394926ffad2': 
   Room {
     sockets: 
      { '/#7GkyyIz7eINlls_1AAAD': true,
        '/#fIefLQfX-VPNp9HFAAAC': true },
     length: 2 },
  '58011b4679dfb394926ffad3': 
   Room {
     sockets: 
      { '/#7GkyyIz7eINlls_1AAAD': true,
        '/#QTxr85JsDbbgfUSdAAAE': true },
     length: 2 } }`

The above tells me that user 1 ends up being in two rooms, which suggests that they are not fully leaving the first one.

I've been trying to solve this for the last two days and just can't find an answer, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems wrong `delete rooms[userId] == data.room;`, it just compares `rooms[userId] == data.room;` that and then try to delete it `delete true` or `delete  false` based on value. It's not actually removing item. To remove the item it should be just `delete rooms[userId]`

Comment: Thanks, I originally had that as `delete rooms[userId]` so I'll change it back. This only changes my `rooms` object though, it has nothing to do with the client leaving the `socket.io` `room`.